# Why Height 100% doesnt working in one div

Tags: css, html

**height 100% is working in some divs and in others doesnt(container).**
Height 100% works in Menu_left div but in container doesnt.
I don't know why it didn't work to set height 100% in that div.

here is my html code:

```
<body>
<div class="All clearfix">
    <div class="Menu_left">Menu</div>
    <div class="Container_right">Container</div>
</div>
</body>
```

My css:

```
html,body,div,span,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,q,s,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,footer,header,menu,section{border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline;margin:0;padding:0}article,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}body{line-height:1}ol,ul{list-style:none}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden; display: block; font-size: 0; content: " "; clear: both; height: 0;
}
* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */


html{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;

}


body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size:cover;
}
.All{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:rgb(35,31,32) ;
}
.Menu_left_float{
    float:left;
    background:blue;
    width:340px;
    height:100%;
    }
.Menu_left{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:340px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#F0F;
}
.Container_right{
    position:relative;
    background-color:#00F;
    min-height:100%;!important
    height:100%;
    margin:0 0 0 340px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/J7QJ2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/jezoqume/1/edit

give `.All` height of `1px` and it will work. 
cheers.

Comment: thanks that worked, but why I have to set .All to 1 px?

Comment: That's because browsers are stupid...it's a bug, and this is a workaround.

Comment: but if I want another div inside Container called Promotion with height 20% why doesn't work?.

Comment: well, because 20% of his parent's height wouldn't work if parent's height is not set in `px`. here's a working example - http://jsbin.com/jezoqume/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

On adding position:fixed instead of position:relative, it is working.

http://jsfiddle.net/SVhm6/

```
.Container_right{
    /*position:relative;*/
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#00F;
    min-height:100%;!important
    height:100%;
    margin:0 0 0 340px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your position:fixed is causing this. When you applied a fixed position, you took ownership of that entire side.

get rid of the fixed position and you'll see. And for more fun, give the other div a fixed position and you'll see that doing it instead!

It's all in the position bud.

So either make them both fixed, or use height auto with relative position. You will be fine either way.